# How do I do a "select all" and "copy to clipboard" with Javascript for an asp:label?

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard

I want to copy the content of an asp:label using javascript.

I can do it using this method:

```
strContent = document.getElementById('MainContent_lblHtml').innerText;
window.clipboardData.setData("Text", strContent);
```

but it strips the formatting and just copies text. (I assume because the dataformat is set to "text".)

The label contains some formatted html. I want to preserve the format, getting the same effect as if I were to highlight it on screen with my mouse, and then copy into (for example) a word document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

The following will highlight the desired div and then copy the HTML to the clipboard.  Go to Word and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the formatted html into a document.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CopyHTMLToClipboard() {    
        if (document.body.createControlRange) {
            var htmlContent = document.getElementById('MainContent_lblHtml');
            var controlRange;

            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(htmlContent);

            //Uncomment the next line if you don't want the text in the div to be selected
            range.select();

            controlRange = document.body.createControlRange();
            controlRange.addElement(htmlContent);

            //This line will copy the formatted text to the clipboard
            controlRange.execCommand('Copy');         

            alert('Your HTML has been copied\n\r\n\rGo to Word and press Ctrl+V');
        }
    }    
</script>
```

Comment: Still not quite what I'm after. You'll have to forgive my ignorance, as I'm not quite sure how it works. If you paste a website contents into Word it'll retain the formatting. If you paste via innerHTML as above it'll put the tags into Word.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I thought you only wanted to copy the HTML itself.  I've updated the code so that copying will allow you to paste fully formatted code into a Microsoft Word document.

Comment: Thanks VERY much! This was driving me crazy!

Comment: Great.  It was driving me crazy too.  It took me a while to figure out.

Comment: "Uncomment the next line if you don't want the text in the div to be selected" should be "Uncomment the next line if you DO want the text in the div to be selected"